# Sync large Realm behavior

Tags: realm, realm-mobile-platform

I want to know how realm handles syncing large Realm on the Realm Mobile Platform.

Let's say I have a chat application. Users and chats. My understanding is that everything gets synced. If the amount of storage available on the phone won't let the entire realm sync, does realm handle this? If so what is the behavior? Do objects that are older get removed from the device?

Comment: `My understanding is that everything gets synced.` not if you use ROS 2.0 and its "currently preview but not for too long" *partial sync* api

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right - the entire Realm gets synchronized. You can split different conversations into different Realms which you can then clean up as you see fit - e.g. remove the **files** (not the data - it will still be available on the server) for inactive conversations.

Alternatively, you can use [Partial Synchronization](https://realm.io/docs/dotnet/latest/#partial-synchronization) to download just the objects that are relevant for the current user.

Comment: Thanks Nikola. Can't wait for partial sync to be out of Beta. Can you provide guidance for creating synchronized Realm's on the fly? The only way I know is from Realm Studio. I always get a fatal exception if I try and open a Synced Realm that is not there. Can I create Synchronized Realms from inside a client SDK? Thanks!

Comment: Of course, there's no reason why you wouldn't be able to create it from the SDK. Which language are you developing with?

Comment: Swift. I've been using Realm to store data locally for a while and know the SDK well. Object server is new. Let's say a new user sign's up in the app. How do I make a Realm just for them? Either some serve side middleware or a call from the client SDK. I could not find a clear guide in the docs. Thank you.

Comment: They can make the Realm themselves from the client side SDK. After they login, just create the realm by passing in `syncConfiguration`: https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest#opening-a-synchronized-realm